# Android Default Toggle Button Showing Through

Tags: android, statelistdrawable

I am creating a custom Toggle Button. Even though I've created a custom image, the default Toggle Button graphic still shows through (pictures below). I've created a selector and referenced it using the `android:background` property.

The selector looks like:

```
<item android:state_checked="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/playon" />

<item android:state_checked="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/playoff" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/playoff" />
```

Where `@drawable/playoff` is http://i41.tinypic.com/sgpugj.png. However, when the toggle button is off it looks like http://i42.tinypic.com/2irap9x.png. As you can see, the "Off" message is "ghosting" as if it still wants to use the default toggle button. Any help on removing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try removing 

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/playoff" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using both `android:button` and `android:background` referencing the same selector.

Answer (score 2):

I used below methods for removing the default text(on/off) in my java file.

```
  tgl_btn.setTextOff("");
  tgl_btn.setTextOn("");
```

Comment: I think using XML properties is more appropriate here.